# How do I open [Dual OS with Win 7] Ubuntu OS 16.04 after already installing it using UNetbootin?

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, lubuntu

I had Dual booted my Win 7 PC with Lubuntu using Unetbootin as per instructions I found for BIOS in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb).

I have been successfully able to install Lubuntu on a drive [Other than `C:/`] on my PC.

> **Q1:** How do I open this OS?

My boot manager shows two boot options:

> 1. Windows 7
> 2. UNetbootin

Ongoing further with Unetbootin, I am given a few options:

> 1. UNetbootin
> 2. Help
> 3. Try Lubuntu without Installing
> 4. Install Lubuntu
> 5. Boot from Hard Disk

These options result in asking to install Lubuntu again.
The device partition that opens up during this repeat installation also shows Ubuntu 16.04 installed on the very drive.

> **Q2:** I would like to know how do I open Lubuntu OS?

Also, any of the options result in a cmd type screen with lots of commands written and going on further... Just like it happened before Installing Lubuntu for the first time.

Any help or clarification will be really appreciated.

**EDIT:** I am using Lubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus) for 32-bit PC (i386).[The *latest* compatible model for a 0.5 GB RAM.]